# Add worklog with no timeSpent, only remaininEstimate using POSTMAN Jira REST API

Tags: postman, jira-rest-api

In the documentation right here :

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#api-rest-api-3-issue-issueIdOrKey-worklog-post

It is indicated that body parameters timeSpent is required when created a worklog.

However, directly in Jira, you can add a worklog with no work time, only remaining Estimate.

However the rest API doesn't allow it, which is unfortunate because what if I want to update the remaining estimate of an issue without actually log in any time ?

**FYI** this is the request that i AM doing :

**https://{server_url}/rest/api/3/issue/issueKey/worklog?adjustEstimate=new&newEstimate=300**

This is in fact modifying the remaining Estimate time of the issue, but it forces me to add a log time of at least one minute.

**Is there any workaround that could allow me to change the remaining time without having to log any work time ?**

I also tried to use the issue update modifying timetracking, but always get the same error message : cannot update field timetracking since it is not on the appropriate screen , or unknown.

Here's the screenshot :

[image]
[image]

I'm starting to think there is currently no way to update remaining estimate time of an issue without inserting work time...

BTW, I can modify summary, description, etc... It looks that only the timetracking is not modifiable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I have to by pass this problem is to fetch all the worklogs of the target issues, select the last one, and update it with this rest request :

https://{server}/rest/api/3/issue/{key}/worklog/{id}?adjustEstimate=new&newEstimate={minutes}

However that requires that there is at least one worklog that has been added to the issue.

So

**Step 1 :**

Fetch every worklog using :

https://{server}/rest/api/3/issue/{key}/worklog/

**Step 2:**

Loop through all worklog to find the most recent one that you are going to update, and retrieve the *timeSpentSeconds* and *id*.

**Step 3**

Update the worklog using this rest request as a **PUT request**

https://{server}/rest/api/3/issue/{key}/worklog/{id}?adjustEstimate=new&newEstimate={minutes}

with the following body :

{
    "timeSpentSeconds":timeSpentSeconds
}

note that you have to send back the timeSpentSeconds with the same number it had before the update to ensure the request call works.

Hope this helps anybody with the same problem that I had.

If anyone have a solution that doesn't require updating a previous worklog, feel free to add a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Timetracking is modifiable in Jira. It looks like you were using the wrong API to update the timetracking fields. Also the error mentioned in the screenshot is not related to modification of time tracking fields. The authentication can be the problem for the error seen in screenshot.Also check for the fields which are visible in Jira UI when you edit the issue. When you try to edit an issue with the REST API you may only set the fields that are visible in that screen.

To only update the remaining estimate field without adding timeSpent, you can try following  Jira Rest URL and Request Payload,

[image]

Jira UI will be updated as below,

[image]

Posting some helpful Jira Rest API links,
https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.0.2/#api/2/issue-addWorklog

https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/#creating-an-issue-examples